# Apache ant override properties file value for each iteration

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am trying invoke ant script from jenkins. The input "myvalues" contains something like -Dmyvalues=abc,xyz.This input can have 'n' number of values. I have set of properties file for example: abc.properties and xyz.properties. I am loading property file dynamically like `<property file="@{prop}.properties"/>`. Now i wanted this property file value to be overriden for each iteration. For example in the first execution i want the values of abc.properties and in the second execution i want the value of xyz.properties. The below code works ok except that for all the iteration only the value from the 1st properties abc.properties file gets assigned for both the iteration. I know the property is immutable. Is there are any other way to achieve what i want ?
My script looks something like this

```
<target name="mytestexecution">
           <echo>Test Execution Begins</echo>
               <for list="${myvalues}" param="prop">
                    <sequential>
        <property file="@{prop}.properties"/>
               <echo message="@{prop}.properties"/>
                <exec executable="${mytest.home}\bin\printfilename.bat">   

<!--here i want c:/tempexec for the first iteration and D:/tempexec for the second iteration -->
                  <arg value="-s${mytest.testresult}" />
                         </exec>                 
                 </sequential>  
    </for>
                 <echo>Test Execution Completed</echo>                                              
       </target>
```